# Copy conditional formatting to all rows so it increases the row number also

Tags: conditional-statements, formatting, copy, paste

Copy conditional formatting to all rows so it increases the row number also i.e. A3:E3 custom formula is =$F3="yes", make next A4:E4 =$F4="yes", then 5, 6 , 7 etc. Currently it keeps custom formula at F3

I;ve tried copy paste special and all options but does not increase